# tensorflow's recall and precision do not mean what they are supposed to mean

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

as in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8375)

tensorflow's streaming recall and precision do not mean what they are supposed to mean

modified from this example from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py)

```
predictions = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
labels = tf.squeeze(labels)
names_to_values, names_to_updates = slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
    'Accuracy': slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions, labels),
    'Precision': slim.metrics.streaming_precision(predictions, labels),
    'Recall': slim.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels),
    'Recall_5': slim.metrics.streaming_recall_at_k(logits, labels, 5),
    'Recall_3': slim.metrics.streaming_recall_at_k(logits, labels, 3),
    'Recall_1': slim.metrics.streaming_recall_at_k(logits, labels, 1),
    })
```

result is like

```
2018-03-06 12:45:43.520961: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Recall_1[0.664843738]
2018-03-06 12:45:43.521368: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Recall[0.990521312]
2018-03-06 12:45:43.521429: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Recall_5[0.857031226]
2018-03-06 12:45:43.521487: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Precision[0.996820331]
2018-03-06 12:45:43.521537: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Accuracy[0.664843738]
2018-03-06 12:45:43.521584: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Recall_3[0.809375]
```

how come both streaming_recall and streaming_precision are 99% while accuracy and top 1 recall are 66%.

something seriously is different than the known meaning of [recall and precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)
we know.  and why accuracy is same as recall_1 and why recall and recall_1 are different?

The question is how to update slim's `eval_image_classifier.py` to make it calculate streaming_recall and streaming_precision and f1 score for non Boolean values?

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the predictions are being cast to boolean which is leading to a tensor of only True values; then recall is 1. If the same thing is happening to labels I can understand how precision is 1.

Comment: would you please give us a snippet that shows how to make it give expected results?

Comment: after looking into the docs you are right, [recall](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/recall) expects both labels and predictions to be bool. I'll update the question to make it what is the proper tf code to get recall, precision, and f1 score